# Coded UI build server integration process

Tags: automated-tests, build-process, coded-ui-tests, specflow, build-server

We would like to integrate an automated functional test solution (developed using SpecFlow and Coded UI) in our build server.

The project looks like this:

- the AUT is a WPF application
- the developers are working with Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- automation testers joined the project with Visual Studio 2012 Premium (VS Premium is needed for Coded UI tests)
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional is installed on the build server
- Jenkins is used
- a VM is configured for the development and a 2nd VM will be used by the testers

Could someone help me with the build-server integration process? 
Which are the main steps to do this? 
Do we need to upgrade the VS version on the build server to 2012 Premium? Are there some other solutions/workarounds?

Note: I'm rookie in terms of integration, build-server configuration etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Building a Coded UI test needs Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 Premium. Running Coded UI tests will need an "agent" computer, can be VM or real. An agent can only run one Coded UI test at a time as Coded UI tests use the mouse, keyboard and screen of the agent. The "agent" software should be a free download from Microsoft. It runs the tests and agent computers do not need Visual Studio installed. You can have multiple agents to allow parallel test execution.

Comment: Hi, I'm also interested in this topic - have you managed to get the automated UI tests integrated in the CI process without installing VS on the build server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're going to want to put your CodedUI tests inside an orderedTest. Right Click on the solution -> add -> orderedTest.
2. You're going to want to install https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTestRunner+Plugin it's not a requirement, but it makes working with mstest in jenkins a little easier.
3. At this point you just need to configure the plugin in jenkins to run your orderedTest. It will need you to point to mstest and the location of your orderedtest.