# How to run Visual studio 2010 Test Project from jenkins?

Tags: .net, vb.net, jenkins, coded-ui-tests

I have Test Project created in **VB** having a coded UI tests to automate the things.
It is running well from visual studio 2010 but,not running properly using MSTest.exe.
I want to run this project from **Jenkins**.What i need to do for that ?

Now i have bat file which contain command to run test project which is running properly from command promt and not from jenkins build .Jenkins is not able to interact with my desktop/system What i need to do for that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coded UI build server integration process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683598/coded-ui-build-server-integration-process)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you want is not easy respectively not possible. If you start a CUIT form Jenkins-batch it will not get control over mouse and keyboard.
We "solve" the problem with manual start our CUIT on Jenkins-Server out of installed Visual Studio. Not ideal but an acceptable solution for the moment.

Hope you get a additional more positive answer ...